# Copy Constructor for not dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

According to definition  : **When an object of this class is copied, the pointer member is copied, but not the pointed buffer, resulting in two objects pointing to the same**  so we use copy constructor. 
 But in following class there is no copy constructor but it Works! why? Why i dont need to deep copying?

```
class Human
{
private:
    int* aValue;

public:
    Human(int* param)
    {
        aValue=param;
    }

    void ShowInfos()
    {
        cout<<"Human's info:"<<*aValue<<endl;
    }
};

void JustAFunction(Human m)
{
    m.ShowInfos();
}

int main()
{
    int age = 10;
    Human aHuman(&age);
    aHuman.ShowInfos();
    JustAFunction(aHuman);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> Human's info : 10
>   Human's info : 10

Comment: "two objects pointing to the same" isn't itself a problem. Problems arise if, for example, both objects try to delete the thing they point to.

Comment: so we can say there is no dangling pointer here? becouse there is no using allocated memory with new? I mean there is no deleting the thing they point to according to example. so there is no possibilty dangling pointer. I mean if i dont allocate a pointer with new so that pointer can be dangling pointer?

Comment: We can say there is no dangling pointer here, because no pointer here outlives the object it points to. Using `delete` is a common source of dangling pointers, but they can also arise when automatic variables go out of scope and when static variables are destroyed at the end of the program - you need to understand object lifetimes before you can use pointers safely.

Comment: Thanks, i ask becouse someone says dangling pointer only occurs if you point dynamic memory with new. like int* p=new int(10); (dangling pointer if delete p).. Not like int* a=&b;(no dangling pointer if b destroyed end of a scope)

Comment: There's no formal definition of "dangling", but it makes more sense to simply use it to mean "invalidated by an object's destruction" rather than restricting it to only destruction via `delete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has already been mentioned, the reason it works for you is that it's actually fine to have multiple pointers pointing to the same object - that's kind of the point, share data without copying it.

the issues arrive if the object pointed to has it's lifetime managed by the wrapping class, ie: it is created and destroyed within methods implemented by the class - typically the class's constructor and destructor.  In that case a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_copy#Deep_copy) would be necessary in the copy constructor.

In your (admittedly contrived) example where the int has a longer lifetime that the object carrying the pointer you should examine using a reference as a member, initialised in an initialiser list.  This removes the possibility of forgetting yourself and deleting the object from within the class.

```
class Human
{
private:
    int& aRef;

public:
    Human(int& param)
    : aRef(param)
    {
    }
};
```

You should also consider whether the pointer or reference should be to a const object:

```
class Human
{
private:
    const int& aRef;

public:
    Human(const int& param)
    : aRef(param)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

A copy constructor is useful when your class owns resources. In your case, it doesn't - it neither creates nor deletes `aValue` itself.

If you did do that though, say:

```
Human()
{
    aValue=new int;
}
```

and properly cleaned up the memory:

```
~Human()
{
    delete aValue;
}
```

then you'd run into issues, because `Human a;` and `Human b(a);` would have the members `aValue` point to the same location, and the when they go out of scope, the same memory is released, resulting in a double delete.

Comment: yes, becouse to prevent deleting dangling pointer, right? so in my example one of destroyed why the other still alive? this is what i want to try to ask

Comment: @VitoCarleone neither is destroyed because you don't call delete. Nor should you, because you didn't allocate it with new.

Comment: forexample after calling JustAFunction m will be destroyed end of scope

Comment: @VitoCarleone yes, but its destructor does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This works because the pointer in the class points to the stack variable `age`.

You haven't written a destructor for your class `Human`, so doesn't try to do a double delete when the `Human` is copied in `JustAFunction`

If you used it differently, for example sending a `new`ed int into the class you would have a memory leak instead.

```
Human human(new int);
```

If you copy that, you have two pointers pointing to the same memory, which in itself isn't a problem, but makes it hard to decide who is in charge of releasing that memory.